# Regular expression number

Tags: java, regex

My target is to format next number `01122222222` to this `011-22-22-22-22`
First three numbers of number, dash and all next numbers with dash after second one. Already tried:

```
private String phoneFormat(String phoneNumber){
    String regex = "\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))";
    String formattedPhone = phoneNumber.replaceAll(regex, Constants.Characters.DASH);
    return formattedPhone;
}
```

but it produce different result.

Comment: regular expression is for finding a certain pattern, not for formatting strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regex will do the trick. Replace sets of 2 digits with "-[digit][digit]" as long as you have 3 digits before those.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "01122222222";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{3})(\\d{2})+?", "-$1"));
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/hH0Ow3)

O/P :

```
011-22-22-22-22
```

PS : This approach should NOT be used in prod environment and has been written solely to please my own stubbornness that this problem can be solved using one regex.

Comment: Nice one. Nit-picking: It's not the regex that does the replacement. It's `replaceAll`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes. I meant the same thing. Edited the answer to change it to *this approach should not*... Also, thanks for the Ideone link :)

Comment: *"This regex should NOT be used in prod environment and has been written solely to please my own stubbornness that this problem can be solved using one regex."* LOL - Because of the positive look-behind?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - No. I am OK with positive lookbehinds. I think the real problem here is that only a few people (who will be reviewing this code) understand how this regex behaves. Thus, *readability* is a problem. My PR would probably get rejected if this code was going into prod :P

Answer (score 2):

Since at first your question wasn't clear, I had a solution for both Java and Javascript. I'll leave the javascript one in here as well just 'cause :-)

### Java 8

First we use `substring(0,3)` to get the first three numbers. We add `-` to this, and with the remaining group (`x.substring(3)`), we split them in groups of two, and we join them together with String.join and use `-` as the concatenating character.

```
String test = "01122222222";
String res = test.substring(0,3) + "-";
String[] parts = test.substring(3).split("(?=(?:..)*$)");
res += String.join("-",parts);

System.out.println(res);
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/l2t1O6)

---

### Pre Java 8

From the comments it became clear that you are not using Java 8, so pre-java8 there are various other solutions. You could use a loop like I have done, and add the last part manually. (Alternatively, you could just create the string with each element in the loop, and take the substring again to remove the last `-`).

```
String test = "01122222222";
String res = test.substring(0,3) + "-";
String[] parts = test.substring(3).split("(?=(?:..)*$)");
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length-1; i++){
    res += parts[i]+"-";
}
res+=parts[parts.length-1];
System.out.println(res);
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/YRT7mO)

---

### Javascript

Using the same logic, you could do this in javascript as well. You can run the snippet to see that the result is actually what you expected.

```js
var x = "01122222222";
var res = x.substring(0,3) +"-"+ x.substring(3).split(/(?=(?:..)*$)/).join("-");
console.log(res)
```

Comment: String.join is invalid

Comment: @TeodorKolev that is because you are using an older version of Java, I have added that solution as well now

Comment: @TeodorKolev: `String.join` was added in Java 8, nearly two and a half years ago.